# number of queries limited in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, throttling

hi
I use a java library(jwpl) to connect a database of mysql.
number of queries that I can be asked on a certain term is limited.
for example query="select * from table where keyword= term" can be asked for about 20 times and after that it doesn't work at all. 
what should I do?
should I change cache parameters of mysql? and how?
thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work at all" mean? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you're using a connection pool but failing to close the connections (and thus not returning them to the pool)?

Check that you're closing everything in finally blocks.